# Center an input field with css

Tags: html, css

I have an input field an width of 20% like you can see here:

```
<input id="saveServer" width="20%"  class="depth"></input>
```

So to center it i add two span elements,with an width:40%, before and after the input field, to center the input field. Like you can see here:

```
<span style="width:40%"></span>
<input id="saveServer" width="20%"  class="depth"></input>
<span style="width:40%"></span>
```

But somehow the the inut field does not center himself. I have no idea how to center it! Greetings from Germany! Thanks!

Heres the same example on fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/bmkc2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sticking to your method, here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmkc2/1/

- to be taken into consideration, a width can't be applied on an inline element like a `span`. You first have to display it as inline-block for example.
- `display: block` on input will display it alone on its own line. Again, inline-block or floating.
- inline-block has one annoyance (it's normal but still annoying here), it'll display whitespace between elements displayed as inline-block, that is a 4px space between each span and input. The HTML comments are there to avoid these spaces (it's normal because imagine two words each in a span and separated by a space. You need and expect this space between words or it'd be unreadable!)
- width: 20% and border-width: 1px and padding 5px will add up and with 2x40% it'll be greater than 100%. `box-sizing: border-box` will avoid that border and padding are taken from the 20% width (check caniuse.com for the complete list of prefix to add -moz-, etc).

edit:

- your input has neither a label (associated with its `for` attribute) nor a title attribute, is it just because it's a demo ?
- `margin: 0 auto` as stated in another answer and `text-align: center` are preferable to adding 2 empty elements just for centering. I just wanted to make your first try work.

Comment: ok the thing is i use the input in an table, because it wasnt recomended to use an label in an table. The first thing i tried was the method with the margin 0 auto. The thing is that im making an app with phongeap and the odd about is that with an android device 2.2 version the input is centering but in the higher versions it isnt. For me it makes no sense that in the lower versions it is centering in the newer versions not. Now i will try your first answer and check if that works! Do you have any clue why it doesnt work correctly on the android devices? Thanks

Comment: It makes me really sad that your websiste is only in frances! But looks very intresting! I will learn french! Greetings from Germany

Answer (score 9):

I think more context would help to clarify the problem, 
but is this what you are after? One way to 
center the input itself is by adding the rule:
`margin: 0 auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/QqRCm/

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code does not work as you think it should is because both the input element and the span element are floated elements.  To get them to work they way you are thinking, you need to have them displayed as inline-block elements.

Add the following code and it will work the way you expect it should.

```
span, #saveServer {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/bmkc2/2/

Answer (score 0):

---------------------------`


.x
{
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}

`-----------
to enter the image copy the link then paste in browser

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJsoq.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).